# (Django 3.1.6/Python 3.8.7) Using a named method in fields or fieldsets admin.py does not work?

Tags: python, django, python-3.8

No matter what I try I cannot use a named method as a field name like they do in the docs.  Eventually I'll make the method retrieve a field of a ForeignKey but for now I just want to figure out what I'm doing wrong with this simplified example.

[In this example from docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.empty_value_display) they are using the class method 'view_birth_date' just as I am using 'get_test' (below) and even through I'm using it in `fieldsets` instead of `fields` it should work.

I've tried it with `fields =`  and `fieldsets =`  and I get the same result (error).  It cannot find the field 'get_test' either way.  I've also tried putting the `def get_test(self)` above the `fieldsets =`  but it makes no difference.

It should work the same as what is in the documentation but it does not.  What am I doing wrong?

**This should work:**

```
@admin.register(Feeddata)
class AdminFeeddata(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Feeddata admin."""

    list_display = ['id', 'eventtime', 'feed']
    fieldsets = [
        ('Meta', {
            'fields': ['feed', 'eventtime', 'get_test']
        }),
        ('JSON Data', {
            'fields': ('json_data', )
        }),
    ]

    # pylint: disable=no-self-use
    def get_test(self):
        """Test string."""
        return 'test'
```

**But I get an error:**

```
FieldError at /admin/feeder/feeddata/fff1d764-52cd-499f-9ae9-b1251a806b5b/change/
Unknown field(s) (get_test) specified for Feeddata. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class AdminFeeddata.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/feeder/feeddata/fff1d764-52cd-499f-9ae9-b1251a806b5b/change/
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Unknown field(s) (get_test) specified for Feeddata. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class AdminFeeddata.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py, line 711, in get_form
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.7
Python Path:    
['/code',
 '/code',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 18 Feb 2021 23:44:12 -0800
```

Comment: have you tried adding second argument to `get_test`? in docs they have `obj` there

Comment: Try adding the obj argument in the get_test function

Comment: @PawełKordowski This makes no difference.  It still cannot even find the 'get_test' function at all.  Same error.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the obj argument which is your instance model in the get_test method

```py
@admin.register(Feeddata)
class AdminFeeddata(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Feeddata admin."""

    list_display = ['id', 'eventtime', 'feed']
    fieldsets = [
        ('Meta', {
            'fields': ['feed', 'eventtime', 'get_test']
        }),
        ('JSON Data', {
            'fields': ('json_data', )
        }),
    ]

    # pylint: disable=no-self-use
    def get_test(self, obj):
        """Test string."""
        return 'test'
```

here an example in documentation:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'title', 'view_birth_date')

    def view_birth_date(self, obj):
        return obj.birth_date

    view_birth_date.empty_value_display = '???'
```

Comment: Tried this but it still cannot even find the 'get_test' function at all.  Same error.

Comment: list_display = ['id', 'eventtime', 'feed', 'get_test'] did you add your customized field to the list_display?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display a custom field in your form fieldset that is the result of a method, you should pass it to the `readonly_fields`. Add `get_test` to the `readonly_fields` list as follows.

```
@admin.register(Feeddata)
class AdminFeeddata(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Feeddata admin."""

    readonly_fields = ["get_test"] #new
    list_display = ['id', 'eventtime', 'feed']
    fieldsets = [
        ('Meta', {
            'fields': ['feed', 'eventtime', 'get_test']
        }),
        ('JSON Data', {
            'fields': ('json_data', )
        }),
    ]

    # pylint: disable=no-self-use
    def get_test(self):
        """Test string."""
        return 'test'
```